# Chrome Ignoring CSS Rule That Shows in Firebug

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

When using Chrome on PC and refreshing our page, sometimes the two paragraph text area where it says "Small Business Finance Team doesn’t stop advocating for its clients..." will ignore its parent div's 580px width rule and display behind the form on the right.

I'm not sure if this is because of the mobile responsive design or the div placement, but it's very strange due to Firebug displaying 580px whether the text is inside or outside the 580px width. The width value is never crossed out to indicate that the rule isn't being used.

Adding different !important rules, paddings, margins and commenting out the mobile area doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Website: http://smallbusinessfinanceteam.com/gold
Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRBof.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the relevant code to the question itself, otherwise this question will be of no use to anyone if and when your website updates or goes down for whatever reason.

Comment: I recommend avoiding !important rules as much as possible in CSS; they're generally considered bad practice for reasons outlined [here](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/).

Comment: @oxguy the use of !important is an objective matter. There are many instances to where it is useful. I wouldn't recommend using it to overwrite a style in the same sheet, but when working with multiple sheets, it's necessary in some cases.

Comment: @JoshSalazar certainly yeah, there are a few use cases for it, but it sounded this wasn't one of those, so I figured I'd just drop a comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the width: 580px property and just keeping the max-width: 580px property on the .left class.

```
.left {
    max-width: 580px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh but this does not fix the issue.